# Enabling a static member conditionally without changing the member scope

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, conditional-statements

I want to enable a static member for a class without changing its scope.
Consider the following abstracted example:

```
template<uint R, uint C>
class Foo
{
    static Foo ID;

    /* other members */
};
```

Now I want to use the static member like:

```
Foo<3, 3> foo = Foo<3, 3>::ID;
```

The problem is that the `ID` field can only exist when `R == C`.
(`Foo` is actually a `Matrix` and `ID` its identity which only exists for square matrices)

So I have to conditionally enable the static `ID` member when the condition is met. My current solution is something like this:

```
struct EmptyBase { };

template<uint R, uint C>
class _Foo_Square
{
    static Foo<R, C> ID;
};

template<uint R, uint C>
class Foo : public std::conditional<R == C, _Foo_Square<R, C>, EmptyBase>::type
{
    /* other members */
};
```

But now I cannot write `Foo<3, 3>::ID` to access it. I have to write `_Foo_Square<3, 3>::ID`.

Unfortunately the design of my application forces it to be accessible by the `Foo` class scope.
If it wasn't a conditional member I could write `using _Foo_Square<3, 3>::ID;` in the Foo class.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Subclassing seems like a good idea.

Comment: "*But now I cannot write `Foo<3, 3>::ID` to access it. I have to write `_Foo_Square<3, 3>::ID`.*" To access it from where? As you've shown, the only "problem" is that `ID` is private...

Comment: yes, your code works if you make it public: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ceb5c6660a0fd8b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is either to fix a few bugs with your code, and/or switch to a better compiler.

After adding a proper forward declaration, and declaring the static class member as `public`, the following compiles without issues with gcc 6.1.1:

```
#include <utility>

struct EmptyBase { };

template<int R, int C> class Foo;

template<int R, int C>
class _Foo_Square
{
public:

    static Foo<R, C> ID;
};

template<int R, int C>
class Foo : public std::conditional<R == C, _Foo_Square<R, C>, EmptyBase>::type
{
    /* other members */
};

void foobar()
{
    Foo<3, 3> a=Foo<3, 3>::ID;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, as always I forgot to put the `public:` in the broken down version here. I have got it in my code but it still fails to compile with my gcc 6.1.1. It just says *was not declared in this scope*

Comment: Works for me. The shown code compiles with gcc 6.1.1

Comment: Yeah i start to believe that there's something else in my code which prevents this. Actually I have got two layers of inheritance but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: This is why questions are required to contain a [mcve]. Otherwise, you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: But anyways I think your soultion is correct for the described problem - so I will accept your answer later

Comment: @bricklore - I confirm: changing `void foobar()` with `int main()`, the code compile with g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Specializing a base class `Bar` you can do something like

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t, std::size_t>
struct Foo;

template <std::size_t, std::size_t>
struct Bar
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
struct Bar<N, N>
 { static Foo<N, N> ID; };

template <std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct Foo : Bar<R, C>
 {
   // other members
 };

int main ()
 {
   Foo<3, 3> foo = Foo<3, 3>::ID;

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest version I can think of:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

template<uint R, uint C>
class Foo
{
    //no ID here
};

template<uint R>
class Foo<R,R>
{
public:
    static constexpr Foo ID = Foo();
};

int main()
{
    Foo<3,3> foo1 = Foo<3,3>::ID; //ok

    Foo<3,4> foo2 = Foo<3,4>::ID; //error
}
```