# Accessing a inherited static member without specifying the scope

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, scope

> Followup to: [Enabling a static member conditionally without changing the member scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552226/1683939)

I have got a static class member which is conditionally enabled when both template variables `R` and `C` are equal.

Now I want to access it without having to specify the scope beforehand - just like with any direct static member.

One can pull variables into the derived classes scope using a `using A::variable;` statement. But as the variable is not available for all `Foo` types, this using declaration will fail when `R != C`.

```
struct EmptyBase { };
template<int R, int C> class Foo;

template<int R, int C>
class _Foo_Square
{
public:
    static Foo<R, C> ID;
};

template<int R, int C>
class Foo : public std::conditional<R == C, _Foo_Square<R, C>, EmptyBase>::type
{
public:
    static Foo SECOND;
    /* other members and functions */

    void A()
    {
        Foo a = ID; //error because of inheritance
        Foo b = Foo<R, C>::ID; //works

        Foo test = SECOND; //works everytime
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo<3, 3> foo;
    foo.A();
}
```

Accessing `ID` directly in the member function does not work as expected.

Comment: `this->ID` should work without `using`. Also `Foo::ID`. You just need to make it a dependent name: plain `ID` is not.

Comment: `//error because of inheritance` Not quite – the error is because `ID` is a dependent name; the fact that inheritance is involved is mostly incidental.

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah but you get what I mean right?

Comment: @bricklore : Sure, but knowing the correct terminology is at least half the battle. Now you can search for 'dependent name' and likely answer this yourself.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes you've got a point there. Unfortunately the gcc compiler doesn't care about these which makes it ten times harder to search for a problem when the only given message is like `not declared in this scope`.

Comment: @bricklore what kind of error message do you expect? If it's reasonable then perhaps gcc could implement it,

Comment: @ildjarn I would have expected it to tell me that there is an ID variable which cannot be accessed because it is a dependent name. There is a difference between "there is something that cannot be used" and "there is nothing at all" in my opinion.

Comment: @bricklore : Wrong respondee. ;-]

Comment: @bricklore there is no "something you cannot use", there us "something that cannot be found using actual lookup rules" (which may differ from expected lookup rules). Perhaps a compiler could try to use expected (incorrect) lookup rules and, if they succeed, issue a hint "ISO C++ requires use of `this->` to access inherited members of the template being defined", or something to this effect.